# How to paste one image to another one, by forcing the former's background as transparent?

Tags: image-processing, image

I have 2 images, `imgBlackOnly` and `imgRedOnly` as below, which already have the same `ImageDimensions`.

[image]

[image]

I want to paste `imgBlackOnly` to cover `imgRedOnly`, while the white part of `imgBlackOnly` is treated as "transparent" as what we did in the tiny software Paint of Windows. Thus my desired output is `imgBlackCoverRed` as below:

[image]

But one point to note is, the white part of `imgBlackOnly` is not totally white (since it is a screen capture from somewhere else), and therefore we need to force some "nearly white" part to be "totally white" by adding a manual threshold.

How can I do that? Many thanks!

---

To avoid misunderstanding, I also want to point out that the original picture of `imgBlackOnly` is not just black. It has several colors, with a "nearly white" background. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the function `ColorReplace[img, color]` is that it takes colors that are similar to (not exactly the same as) `color` and replaces those pixels with transparent pixels.

```
i1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPPys.png"];
i2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdDgSs.png"];
i1 = ColorReplace[i1, White];
i2 = ColorReplace[i2, White];
ImageCompose[i1, i2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may notice that there are still some white pixels around the black figure. We can fix that by providing our own threshold for how far away a color can be from white and still be considered similar:

```
i2 = ColorReplace[i2, White, 0.5];
ImageCompose[i1, i2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
imgBlack=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdDgSs.png"];
imgRed=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPPys.png"];
ImageCompose[imgRed,RemoveBackground[imgBlack]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The threshold mentioned by @C.E. can also be used with [`RemoveBackground`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html) to remove the white edge.

```
Module[
 {img1, img2},
 {img1, img2} = Import /@ {
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdDgSs.png",
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPPys.png"};
 ImageCompose[
  img2,
  RemoveBackground[img1, {White, 0.5}]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

`cover=#2~ImageCompose~SetAlphaChannel[#1, ColorNegate@#1] &`

`cover[imgBlackOnly,imgRedOnly]`